# In AndroidManifest: Expecting android:screenOrientation="unspecified"

Tags: android, android-manifest, screen-orientation

Android Studio 3.6.

I want my app to be always in `portrait` mode. So in my `AndroidMainfest.xml`:

```xml
<activity
   android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I run the app and `SplashActivity` shows in `portrait` mode. Nice.
But the editor shows the following error:

```
Expecting android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
```

Why?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

In your manifest tag (just under `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`), put

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Then inside the application tag, put

```
tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"
```

Comment: or if you already have tools:ignore in application tag then set as tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning,LockedOrientationActivity"

Answer (score 25):

it only affects Android Studio 3.6+

What is the Issue here?
This issue occurs because android framework wants user to control the app orientation himself it is not advised to restrict your app orientation for example if a user wants to use the app in landscape orientation he just flips the device and sensors will do the work but when a developer restrict screen orientation, even when rotation sensor works app will stay in pre-defined state, in a way you are restricting user's device capabilities.

What to do now?
You have two options., 
First is to ignore the error as it won't cause any build failure even I am doing the same and apk/aab generation is as usual
Another Option is to provide Landscape Layouts or to handle the rotation like in some apps which recognize if orientation gets changed they will prompt the user to change the orientation as the app is not supported in such orientation

It may change in future => at present it is not effecting our build process but it might change in future

Comment: - Hey! Engineers want to restrict app using in landscape mode. Lets give them screenOrientation tag. In a while: - Hey! Users want to control orientation with phone rotation. Lets restrict using of screenOrientation  tag.

Answer (score 11):

In Android studio 3.6.0 i guess they want the user to handle the orientation and encourage developer to use **ViewModel** stuff. 
Let me explain screenOrientation in detail

`android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

will give you error you have to either specify

`android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" or android:screenOrientation="unspecified"`

**fullSensor** Means either you have ON the "Rotate off" or not it will change the orientation based on you move the phone

**unspecified** Means if you have ON the Rotate off then it will stay only in that orientation and if not then it will change the orientation based on you move the phone.

Answer (score 7):

Add following line after `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

```
tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"
```

Then click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: I can't ... This error is fixed in newest version of Android Studio  ...  It was recommendation from Android Studio yellow dot ...

Answer (score 6):

I found 2 way of solving this problem

First,

```
Android Studio -> Preferences (for Mac) or Settings (for Windows)
-> Search "chrome" 
-> Uncheck "Activity is locked to an orientation" 
-> Apply and Ok 
-> Sync Project with Gradle file
```

Second,

```
Select "Run" from the main menu 
-> Edit Configurations.
-> Launch options - Launch
-> Select Nothing or Specified Activity
-> Sync Project with Gradle file
```

Comment: This seems the right answer to the problem. You should have the option of turning off this warning, and the logical place would seem to be under Preferences. But the first option did not exist on my Mac Android Studio and the second stopped the app running.

The tools:ignore command does the same thing but it can sit in the code next to the screenOrientation command that triggered it. maybe this is why they are pushing us this way.

Answer (score 5):

```
tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning,LockedOrientationActivity"
```

Comment: Can you please explain as well what is the use of this code.

Answer (score 4):

I have used the below Procedure. It works perfectly for me. In Android studio 3.6.0 I think they want the user to handle the orientation and encourage the developer to use ViewModel stuff. Use the below Procedure to ignore that.

Firstly Add :

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

in the manifest tag.

Secondly, Add

```
tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"
```

in application tag. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue, In my requirement, some of the activity will support both orientations and remains will keep in portrait, In this case, I resolved by the following steps:

***Case-1:-*** To lock Orientation

**Step-1:**
 Please Add following line ***Application tag in AndroidManifest.xml***

> tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"

```
<application
android:name=".activity.MyApplication"
tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
```

**Step-2:** If you want to lock screen orientation either in portrait or landscape
 add the following line in the activity tag

> android:screenOrientation="portrait" or "landscape"

***Case-2:-*** Suppose if u want to allow orientation in particular activity and have a specific design for  landscape

**Step-1:** 
Remove Orientation value in configchanges and remove screen orientation if it exists from activity tag, and my personal suggestion use (LifecycleObserver) in Activity for without losing values while changing orientation.

> android:configChanges="orientation"
>   android:screenOrientation="portrait" or "landscape"

This is the way I resolve this issue, hope it helps, Thanks & Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
if(MainActivity.this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation== Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    MainActivity.this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: if orientation portrait locked the orientation of that activity. which means orientation never changed to landscape.

Answer (score -2):

Try putting  the following in the activity tag

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: Not help. It's portrait and landscape mode

Comment: Updated the answer you will have to add both