# How to enable/disable device portrait mode in android programmatically?

Tags: android, screen

I want to enable/disable device portrait mode from service. I know how to set an activity portrait but this is not my requirement. using below code we can set our app orientation but I need to enable/disable the device portrait.

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i searched from internet and i saw this answered question and you can try the link below answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60400979/15805169
then in your manifest file go to activity tag and write this code

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

i hope it will work.

Comment: thank you. but this is only valuable when we set our app Orientation. I found solution.  public void setPortrait(boolean enable) {
        Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, enable ? 1 : 0);
    }

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. We can enable device auto rotate mode with this code.

```
public void setPortrait(boolean enable) {
        Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, enable ? 1 : 0);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can lock screen orientation over all application use this property in application tag in AndroidManifast  `tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"`